# WAS MQ 7.5.x Queue access control

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I have a qmgr `QM1` and local queues `Q1 and Q2`. There is a `SVRCONN` channel with `MCA` set to `mqm`.

There are multiple application connect to my `QMGR` for example `APP1 and App2`.
I want `App1` only have `PUT` authority which means **ONLY PUT** message to `Q1 or Q2` and `App2` only have `GET` authority to **ONLY GET** message from `Q1 or Q2`.

Is there any advice.

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc%2Ffa12730_.htm

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov, I'm using 'setmqaut' but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: you can refer to below page:
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933555/mq-security-getting-a-2035-on-one-queue). hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each unique set of authorizations needs to be attached to a group. Then when the app connects it needs to do so as a user ID in the appropriate group. (Remember that access requests always resolve to a specific principal, but authorizations are attached to groups.)

In this case, App1 and App2 each need their own group and at least one ID that is in each group.  Once you have groups for app1 and app2, then you need to arrange that the `MCAUSER` of the running channel is a user ID in the appropriate group. You can do this by having different channels with hard-coded `MCAUSER` in each, or dynamically set the `MCAUSER` based on CHLAUTH rules.  If you have been using channel security exits such as BlockIP2 or MQAUSX then you can configure those to dynamically set the `MCAUSER` at connect time as well.

Remember that the channels with `MCAUSER('mqm')` set must be configured to deny access to App1 and App2, or any other non-admin connection.  It is much more common and better from a security standpoint to set `MCAUSER('*NOACCESS')` in *all* inbound channels and then override that with exits or CHLAUTH rules.  That way if the channel configuration fails, it fails to a secure state rather than an insecure state.

Answer (score 1):

> There is a SVRCONN channel with MCA set to mqm.

No wonder setmqaut doesn't work.  Every client connection UserID will be overwritten with mqm UserID.

Remove the UserID from MCAUSER field of the channel, so that your security setup will start working.  Secondly, you will need to look up how to protect your queue manager from client applications using the wrong UserID (intentionally or not).